# Copying and overwriting a file from python then reading it

Tags: python

This is what I wrote for python:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print("Let's see what we have in the file we want to copy:")
open_file = open(from_file)
read_file = open_file.read()
print(read_file)

print("Now let's see what we have in the file we want to copy to:")
new_file = open(to_file)
new_read = new_file.read()
print(new_read)

print(f"Now let's copy stuff from {from_file} to {to_file}")
new_file2 = open(to_file, 'w')
new_file2.write(read_file)
new_file2.close()

print(f"Now let's see what is in {to_file}")
new_file3 = open(new_file2)
new_read2 = new_file3.read()
print(new_read2)
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Can someone tell me what exactly I did wrong here or what I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you Google'd that error message, what did you find?

Comment: You probably should get into the habit of using `with open`, its much less likely to leave files accidentally open.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  You haven't listed a problem; an off-site screen shot is not acceptable.

Comment: @dfundako Thank you. I did google it but I didn't understand because the explanations seemed too complicated. Could you maybe explain it to me the simplest way possible?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```
print(f"Now let's copy stuff from {from_file} to {to_file}")
new_file2 = open(to_file, 'w')
new_file2.write(read_file)
new_file2.close()

print(f"Now let's see what is in {to_file}")
new_file3 = open(new_file2)
```

`open` requires a file name (string).  You gave it a file descriptor, instead.  Try

```
new_file3 = open(to_file)
```

Note that this matches the messages you're printing for the user.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I didn't know we couldn't open through a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

This is cleaning up all of the excess "new_file#" and forgotten file closes using `with open` and re-use of variable names:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print("Let's see what we have in the file we want to copy:")
with open(from_file) as open_file:
    read_file = open_file.read()
    print(read_file)

print("Now let's see what we have in the file we want to copy to:")
with open(to_file) as new_file:
    new_read = new_file.read()
    print(new_read)

print(f"Now let's copy stuff from {from_file} to {to_file}")
with open(to_file, 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(read_file)

print(f"Now let's see what is in {to_file}")
with open(to_file) as new_file:
    new_read = new_file.read()
    print(new_read)
```